# Show correlation index in ggduo scatterplot matrix

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have something like this:

```
library (GGally)
df = data.frame(runif(100),
                rnorm(100),
                rgamma(100,1,2),
                rt(100,1),
                rf(100,1,2))

ggduo(df,columnsX = 1:2, columnsY = 3:5,
      types = list(continuous = "points"))

ggduo(df,columnsX = 1:2, columnsY = 3:5,
      types = list(continuous = "cor"))
```

The first plot shows a matrix of scatterplots , and the second shows the correlations between variables.

Then I'd like to display the correlations in the scatterplots. I think I can do it by merging several scatterplots with `cowplot`, but is it possible within `ggduo`?

**Edit:** I posted a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50854067/show-correlation-index-in-ggduo-scatterplot-matrix-with-coloring).

Comment: Did you see the "psychademic" example in the documentation?  That shows making a loess smoother while adding correlations via a custom function.  Note that in current versions of ggplot2 the lines like `x <- eval(mapping$x, data)` in the function need to be replaced by `x <- eval_data_col(data, mapping$x)`.  See [here](https://github.com/ggobi/ggally/issues/280)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it resolved the first step of my question. I posted a further question as linked in the edit.

Comment: Great!  You should put your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the document, it will display the correlation.

```
library (GGally)
df = data.frame(runif(100),
                rnorm(100),
                rgamma(100,1,2),
                rt(100,1),
                rf(100,1,2))

# from help
PointsWithCor <- function(data, mapping, ..., method = "pearson") {
  x <- eval(mapping$x, data)
  y <- eval(mapping$y, data)
  cor <- cor(x, y, method = method)
  ggally_points(data, mapping, ...) +
    ggplot2::geom_label(
      data = data.frame(
        x = min(x, na.rm = TRUE),
        y = max(y, na.rm = TRUE),
        lab = round(cor, digits = 3)
      ),
      mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = x, y = y, label = lab),
      hjust = 0, vjust = 1,
      size = 5, fontface = "bold",
      inherit.aes = FALSE # do not inherit anything from the ...
    )
}

# plot
ggduo(df,columnsX = 1:2, columnsY = 3:5,
      types = list(continuous = PointsWithCor)))
```